# Cropping rectangular area from bitmao using YuvImage produces strange result

Tags: android, android-imageview, crop, yuv, android-bitmap

I have attempted to crop image from a Bitmap using YuvImage like this:

```
        Bitmap bitmap=params[0];
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
        byte[] data=bos.toByteArray();
        //bos=null;
        YuvImage yuvImage=new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),null);
        bos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        boolean isCropped=yuvImage.compressToJpeg(rect, 100, bos);
        if(isCropped)
            data=bos.toByteArray();
        bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        return bitmap;
```

This causes the resulting image[image: Strange and scary...like an old Black and White TV]

Is there an alternate approach in order to crop and save the image without using the `Intent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You consider Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG as ImageFormat.NV21 which shouldn't be true.

Comment: How to convert YuvImage to Bitmap or show it in an ImageView?

Comment: @user2309862 I don't think there is a convenience function for that. You can however search and use some open source code, I guess.

Comment: @user2309862 No, I don't think so.